# Invalid time representation in momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My API returns the folowing date-time string `my_date = "11 04 2021 20:02"`

I am using the following js code to present this `date moment(my_date).format('DD MMMM YYYY HH:MM')`

But I received wrong time 04 **november** (i expected 11 april)

How can i fix the code?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide the date input format to give instruction to moment on how to read that.

```
moment(my_date, 'DD MM YYYY HH:mm').format('DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm')
```

Please refer [Moment Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for more details on formatting tokens.

Comment: This is correct otherwise, but please note that `MM` and `mm` are not the same thing.